# MYSQL how to use ADDTIME and TIMEDIFF if some column is NULL?

Tags: mysql

[image: Table Structure]

```
"SELECT user,time_in1,time_out1,time_in2,time_out2,time_in3,time_out3,
 DATE(time_in1) AS 'date',
 DAYNAME(DATE(time_in1)) AS 'dow',
 TIME_TO_SEC(ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(time_out1,time_in1),ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(time_out2,time_in2),TIMEDIFF(time_out3,time_in3))))/3600 AS 'total_hour'
 FROM attendance
 WHERE status=0"
```

[image: Result]

Q1.
Above query is use to get staff working hour, but sometimes time2 and time3 can be empty, how can I still calculate the total_hour instead of return NULL when time2 and time3 is empty?

Q2.
MYSQL ADDTIME function can only pass in two date? is that any other way if I want to add more than two date? currently Im write in this way `ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(time_out1,time_in1),ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(time_out2,time_in2),TIMEDIFF(time_out3,time_in3)))` any other suggestion?

Comment: You said `time2` can be `null`. Do you mean `time_in2` and `time_out2` both when you say `time2`? Same for `time3`?

Comment: @JHS both will be null, if time_in2 has data then time_out2 wont be null, same for time3